# Google image search date filter workaround

Tags: web-scraping, google-search, google-image-search

From what I understand, Google removed custom date range filters for image searches around 2018 - 2019. I was wondering if anyone has found a workaround.

- Are there other image search engines that allow you to filter images in this way?
- Is there a way to access image metadata (such as to see when it was indexed or posted)? That way I can sort images after downloading them.
- Can I filter by custom date range on a general google search and somehow access google images from there?

Any ideas, no matter how scuffed, are appreciated. thank you!

*I have tried adding after:yyyy-mm-dd and before:yyyy-mm-dd in my search query but it only works after 2009.

** I have also tried appending url params like "&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1/14/2010,cd_max:6/25/2011" but it doesnt seem to be working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command in the search bar works:

#date_range:YYYYMMDD-YYYYMMDD

e.g. #date_range:20120301-20120307